# iOS - IAP - Is it possible to auto enrol a user on a "premium" subscription on app download that auto expires after 2 weeks?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an app and as part of some enhancements I'm making I want to offer users with a 2 week free trial upon app download/update.

**Is it possible to automatically subscribe a user to the premium trial on app download/app update and after 2 weeks have this auto expire?**

Basically the idea is give users premium features on download by default and then after 2 weeks downgrade them to the free tier but I'd like to do this all automatically

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: you might be better off asking for android and ios individually

Comment: You cant actually 'purchase' a subscription without user interaction, but you can record the date that the user starts using the app and just unlock the premium features for 2 weeks.  You will have to look at ways of recording the date so the user can't simply uninstall the app and reinstall to get another two weeks.  You could store a date in the keychain or use the DeviceCheck api  Having them purchase a subscription with a free trial is possibly easier